# ipv6 address assignment via local server from isp assigned block

Tags: dhcp, bind, ipv6

I have been looking around and found the information confusing as best.  Is there a way to have a server "recieve" the /64 ipv6 block from the isp and then use dhcp or something to assign it out to the local machines so that

1) dns entries are correct for ipv6 addresses? Im sure a script needs to be written so that the external dns host for the domain can be updated as the ns for the local domain shifts around.

2) internal machines can be assigned addresses in a logical manner as well as management from a server can be done. I understand that the addresses will/can change due to isp. I am trying to find a way for those dynamic addresses to be managed/assigned in a straightforward manner

I am running a freeipa server in centos 7 that I hope to be able to have the dns properly updated from/through.  but if there is a better tool out there that I can find a way to integrate in to freeipa that would work as well.

Comment: Did your ISP give you _only_ a /64? They should give you much more than that (RFC 6177). If you only have a small network with one subnet, then it won't be an issue, but that's not likely in any but the smallest home offices.

Comment: sadly yes and its even a business account intended for having servers.

Comment: Interesting I poked around on the forums for my isp... "My Static IP v4 modem just picked up IPv6 ip addresses in Spokane, Washington
It's interesting to note the /64 subnet as well." 

The /64 is for the LAN, you are really getting a /56

Comment: Is the /64 permanently assigned to you or is it given to you via DHCP?

Comment: I believe dhcp but have not had time to poke around with it yet.